# Duplicated Onedrive icon in explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, onedrive, duplicate

I've installed windows 10 on a new pc, with a secondary hard disk containing my onedrive folder, taken from my old pc. I've configured onedrive in order to use that folder, and it's working fine.

The problem is that when I open Explorer I can see two onedrive icons on the sidebar, both of them pointing at the same folder.

How can I remove the duplicated onedrive entry from the sidebar?

[image: Duplicated OneDrive entry]

Comment: I've found a solution here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/duplicated-onedrive-entry/1d447bd8-950c-44ee-8a15-cc1a7be6a3d8

Answer (score 63, accepted):

[According to Microsoft Forum Moderator Ruizell Rey:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/duplicated-onedrive-entry/1d447bd8-950c-44ee-8a15-cc1a7be6a3d8)

> To resolve your concern regarding duplicated OneDrive entry, follow
>   the steps below:
>
> 1. Search for **regedit**, and then press **Enter**.
> 2. Open **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\​Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace**
> 3. Check if you have several folders under NameSpace.
> 4. If there are several folders, highlight each folder, and then check the name of the **Data** on the right hand side.
>
>    [image: OneDrive in Registry Editor]
> 5. If you see multiple folders with OneDrive as the Data, right click on it, and then select **Delete**.
>
>    [image: Deleting registry key]
>
> **Important:** This section, method, or task contains steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur
>   if you modify the registry incorrectly. Therefore, make sure that you
>   follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the
>   registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a
>   problem occurs. For more information about how to back up and restore
>   the registry, refer to the following Microsoft Knowledge Base article.
>
> [How to back up and restore registry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/322756/how-to-back-up-and-restore-the-registry-in-windows) and [Creating a system
>   restore point.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/e6bbddb0-9db4-4d88-9063-42c52c79a96e/create-a-system-restore-point)

Comment: Why does this happen?  It just happened to me, so I completely uninstalled OneDrive.  After doing so, the "duplicate" entry was still visible in Explorer even though OD was not installed.

Comment: For me, it was OneDrive and then OneDrive (my work). Sounds like OneDrive is detected in multiple locations or has a distinct name which makes it show twice.

Comment: Obvious bug that no one seems to have noticed at Microsoft.  Not even sure where to report it.

Comment: In case taking a backup of the registry is forgotten, Windows stores a backup copy of the _System's_ registry stores in `%WinDir%\System32\config\RegBack` _(it does not maintain a backup of the user's registry stores located in `%UserProfile%`)_

Comment: I always have this problem with new installs (Windows 11 this time), with one entry as 'One Drive' and the other 'One Drive <Business Name>'. I found two entries under 'NameSpace' and was easily able to identify and purge the one without the business name using this method.

Answer (score 15):

I have another solution, since i didn't find the folder `...\Desktop\NameSpace` in my registry.

I searched the registry, using the following settings: Search only by Data, text "OneDrive", comparing the whole string. The fourth entry i found was something like this:

`HKEY_USERS\[User-ID]\Software\Classes\CLSID\[XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX]`

The only thing i had to change was setting `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` to `0`, then the wrong entry disappeared.

If you try this, make sure you copy the key and store it before you make any changes. You can set the key value to `1` again, if you picked the wrong entry.

Comment: Not sure if Microsoft did away with the accepted answers regs keys for new versions of Windows 10 but this answer is the solution for me.   My Windows version from system properties is "20H2" build 19042.804, fresh install. Also, after changing the reg value you can re-open File Explorer right away to see your changes and to verify the icon is gone.

Comment: This worked for me but instead of HKEY_USERS I looked in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}